# Tab navigation keyboard shortcut for webstorm

Tags: webstorm

I wish this task did not take up so much of my time.

I am using webstorm along with VIM plugin active on MAC.
Attempting to navigate between open tabs(code files) using keyboard shortcuts.

As per intellij shortcut guide one must use Ctrl + Alt + left arrow or
Ctrl + Alt + right arrow.
( http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/IntelliJ.html )

Went through webstorm settings and couldn't locate the keyboard short guide.

Googled enough
However these shortcuts are not working.

Any clue how to make this work ?

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut you described is "Navigate backward", which is not what you are looking for. Furthermore, the shortcuts you linked are for Windows, not MAC.

The actions you want are "Select Next/Previous Tab". According to the [MAC shortcut list](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) (PDF), the shortcuts are <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd>.

You might want to look into "Recent Files" (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) and "Recently Changed Files" (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>), which is usually faster than switching tabs manually.

Comment: Control + Right / Left results in moving between desktops in Mac. It would  be safe to assume that no keyboard shortcuts are linked to tab navigation by default in WebStorm

Comment: Then look up the shortcut in your IDE. I mentioned the action names, so either open the settings dialog and `Keymap`, or press Command + Shift + A. Then type "Select Next Tab", and if a shortcut is already assigned, you will see it. If not, assign one.

Comment: For the record, it's **Alt-Left/Alt-Right** (Windows). I just looked it up and tried it too. For some reason - despite *desperately*  needing it since forever - I never learned that shortcut.